# How can I auto generate index name with elasticsearch library for python ?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to create for each execution an index with an auto generated name and return it. I'm using elasticsearch library for python as following :

```
x=uuid.uuid4();
print ("index creation ---->")
for key, value in dic.items():
    es.index(index=x, doc_type='doc',body=value, id=key)
return x
```

Actually I'm using uuid to generate an auto ID and I get this error

**TypeError: 'UUID' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a UUID.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting `x` to string should do:

```
es.index(index=str(x), doc_type='doc',body=value, id=key)
```